# How to use Public Method "show Month" in React day picker to Show the given month in the calendar?

Tags: react-day-picker

How to use Public method especially show Month function in React day picker to Show the given month in the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Your can user refs
Here is a example with react hooks

```
const Calender = () => {
  const calRef = useRef<DayPicker>(null);
  const showNextMonth = () => {
    if (calRef.current !== null) calRef.current.showNextMonth();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DayPicker ref={calRef} />
      <button onClick={showNextMonth}>Next Month</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```